# Vectorized euclidean distance between 2 dataset in r

Tags: r, vectorization, euclidean-distance

I have 2 data frames (temp_inp & temp) with 5 & 50k rows respectively and both of them having around 3k columns.

I want to calculate euclidean distance [(x1-x2)^2- no need to take square roots or divide by nrow - I just need the rows with minimum distance] between all the rows of dataframe1 against dataframe 2.

Final output required will have 
rows = rows from temp(50k)
columns = rows from temp_inp(5)

After which I want to take the 5 rows with minimum distances from data frame 1.

Note that something like rbind & dist function will not work due to the size of the data. What I tried is this:

```
for (i in c(1:nrow(temp_inp))) {
for (j in c(1:nrow(temp))) {
  temp1[j,i] <- sum((temp[j,]-temp_inp[i,])^2)
}}
```

This is taking insane amount of time... (8 hours)
I tried racking my to find a vectorized version of the same code. Please help me if you have any idea regarding this or know of any in-built function/package which will help me do so.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdist/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Roland . However, when I use pdist, all the distances are coming as 0 :(
Code I used:
distance <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(pdist(temp_inp[,-1],temp[,-1])))

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass two matrices.